# How to specify crossed random effects in lme?

Tags: random-effects-model, structural-equation-modeling, lme4-nlme

I know that `lmer()` from `lme4` is the function to use to specify complex random effects.

However, I need to translate the following `lmer()` functions into `lme()`from `nlme` package, to be able to use them in the package `piecewiseSEM`:

```
canopy_mfinal <- lmer(log(Canopy) ~ Bulk_Density + H + fGrazing +   
                      (1|NVC) + (1|Site), data = marsh.ok)

elevation_mfinal <- lmer(DGPS_Z ~ Penetrometer + Shear_B + 
                    (1|Site/Creek) + (1|NVC), data = marsh.ok)
```

Any ideas about how this can be done?

Comment: Just to make sure: NVC and Site are crossed, I assume?